# How do I add a scale up effect using Geo Nodes?

Tags: workflow, geometry, geometry-nodes

I'll try to keep it short and precise. I instanced a bunch of cubes of random scaling on my geometry and made it so that it reveals itself along the Z axis with a particular value. Now, I want the cubes nearest to my "reveal" threshold to scale up from 0 to its size. I know it has some stuff to do with the Position field, the threshold value, and a bit of maths, all between the Separate XYZ and Math nodes, but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i understood you right, you wanna make this:

[image]

and you can do this with this node setup:

[image]